# How do i rename json key using python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have json file, i need to rename `folder_path` key to `backup_folder_path` using python:

```json
{
  "urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:smth": {
    "bim_manifest_urn": "urn:foo/bar/z",
    "gs_id": "foobar",
    "versions": {
      "1": "1"
    },
    "folder_path": "/foo/bar"
  },
  "urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:smth": {
    "bim_manifest_urn": "urn:foo/bar",
    "gs_id": "foobar1",
    "versions": {
      "1": "1"
    },
    "folder_path": "/foo/barС"
  },
```

What I tried to do:

```py
def edit_string_name():
    with open(r"smth.json", encoding="utf-8") as json_data:
        data = json.load(json_data)
        
        data = {'folder_path'}
        data['backup_folder_path'] = data.pop('folder_path')
        print(data)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    edit_string_name()
```

But nothing seems to happen.
When I tried to cycle through I got nonsense in terminal.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: attach  the 'nonsense' here

Comment: You can't "rename" a key. You should add the new key and delete the old one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job

```py
def edit_string_name():
  with open("smth.json", "r+", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    data    = json.load(file)
    content = data["urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:smth"]

    content["backup_folder_path"] = content["folder_path"]
    content.pop("folder_path")
    data["urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:smth"] = content

    # Updating the file
    file.seek(0)
    file.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
    file.truncate()

edit_string_name()
```

Comment: This solution causes error  file.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable

Comment: Did you set the flag right? It's should be "r+". What version of python did you using? It''s work fine in python v3.10.9. If it stil not working just create a global var to save the json, then open the file again with the "w" flag and write the global var

Comment: i'm sorry, i fixed the flag and everything worker fine, but the content of backup_folder_path broke.. "backup_folder_path": "/\u042f\u041f30/Project Files/3. \u0423\u0442\u0432\u0435\u0440 etc...

Comment: Did you set the encoding right?

Comment: Yap, encoding is UTF-8